# Can I import more than 15 Grafana customised dashboards without receiving any error using Helm or direct kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, configmap

If i use Helm, I am getting

> "one or more objects failed to apply", reason Configmap "Grafana-configs" is invalid [metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes. []: Too long must have at most 1048576 bytes.

If i use Kubernetes to deploy Grafana along with customised dashbords [15 no's] also getting the above error.

[image: Screnshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

> A ConfigMap is not designed to hold large chunks of data. The data stored in a ConfigMap cannot exceed 1 MiB. If you need to store settings that are larger than this limit, you may want to consider mounting a volume or use a separate database or file service.

So if you store 15 dashboards in the configmap, then you will very likely reach configmap 1MiB size limit.

You can use Helm to deploy 15 dashboards, but definetely you can't use a helm chart, which use config map for that.